# Flutter Wrap ListView.builder Horizontal

Tags: flutter

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: data[1].store.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Wrap(
            children: [
              Text(data[1].store[index].number.toString()),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

I used ListView.builder, I want to wrap Horizontal & scroll Vertical,.
I spend a lot of time on this stack...

My data from local JSON, with Future Builder and return to ListView.builder...

please see attach..

Thanks All...

[image: debug in simulator]

Answer (score 1):

Replace your Container with the below code.

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
          children: [
            Wrap(
              children: List<Widget>.generate(
                1000,
                (int index) {
                  return Text(index.toString() + ' ');
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        )),
```

Comment: @Nang Kho I this is you want.

Comment: My data from local JSON, i used Future Builder and return to ListView.builder...

Comment: what happen when you replace 1000 with `data[1].store.length`

Comment: Still got error,,

RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderSingleChildViewport#3b363 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1702 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was
    SingleChildScrollView